# Create variables from arbitrary number of observations per ID in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset

I’m trying to create 4 new variables from a dataset in R that contains a varying number of observations for each identifier (ID). I want to summarize this information into 2 flags that indicate whether an ID has an observation of type A or B and 2 counter variables containing the total number of A's and B's per ID.

```
ID<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)
Result<-c('A','A','B','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B')
DSN<-data.frame(ID,Result)
```

The output would be:

```
    ID  A_Flag  B_Flag  A_Count B_Count
    1   Y   Y   6   1
    2   N   Y   0   6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest is to use `xtabs`:

```
> xtabs(~ID+Result, DSN)
   Result
ID  A B
  1 6 1
  2 0 6
```

Obviously a flag can be trivially derived from the above:

```
> xtabs(~ID+Result, DSN) > 0
   Result
ID      A    B
  1  TRUE TRUE
  2 FALSE TRUE
```